# Transactions or procedures for multiple queries, which depend on previous queries in transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, recursive-query

I'm trying to figure out which approach is better for implementing a multiple queries if each next query in the transaction depends on the results of the previous one.

For example, there is some table

```
id |  values
1  |   253
2  |   742
...|   ...
```

And the first query in the query stack returns the value **v1** of field *values* from the row with the given *id*. The second query in the query stack should return the value **v2** of field *values* from the row with *id* equal to **v1** returned by the previous query, etc.
I understand that the task may seem strange, but this is a simplified version of a more complex and useful task which is need to be solve.

The first (easiest) way to solve it for me is to combine this multiple requests depending on each other in one transaction. However, I can't find any information related to how the described query stack will be executed inside a single transaction. Will each next query within a transaction wait for a previous query response? Whether time will be spent each time sending a request to the database and waiting for a response from it, or whether all requests will be sent to the database simultaneously with one transaction and waiting for a response from the database will happen once?

I'm trying to understand - is there an advantage to using procedures on the DBMS side?

I suppose that using procedures can reduce the number of queries from the application to the database. And I suppose that every such request is expensive.

I ask the answer to the question - which of the approaches is better to use for the described task in order to increase the performance and reduce the time on interaction with the database?

Thank you!

UPD:

I also tried to use the queries with recursive cte for solving this task.

Unfortunately, in the real task, I have to use such a recursive query at each iteration of another recursive query. The algorithm turns out to be quite complicated and it becomes difficult for me to develop it. So, the question is - maybe using a lot of queries in one transaction described at the application level will give a similar result in performance? But I'm afraid that this approach will lead to waiting for a responses from the database for each request and will be very slow.

Or I can combine the approaches - that is, read part of the data using a recursive cte, then form the next recursive cte based on the data received from previous recursive cte, etc. And perform them all in one transaction.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing an iterative process, that can be implemented in SQL with a recursive query.

In Postgres, it looks like:

```
with recursive cte as (
    -- anchor
    select id, values, 0 lvl from mytable where id = ?
    union all
    -- recursion
    select t.id, t.values, lvl = 1
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on c.values = t.id
)
select * from cte
```

The anchor selects the starting row by `id`, then the recursive part follows the relationship until it exhausts. You might want to read [Postgres documentation on this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) for more details and explanation.

Although likely more efficient than the repeated queries approach, recursive queries are not very efficient against a deeply nested hierarchy; SQL is a *set-based* language, that is not primarly designed for this type of activity.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the real task, I have to use such a recursive query at each iteration of another recursive query. And there are 3 such nested queries.The algorithm turns out to be quite complicated and it becomes difficult for me to develop it. So, the question is - maybe using a lot of queries in one transaction described at the application level will give a similar result in performance?

But I'm afraid that this approach will lead to waiting for a responses from the database for each request and will be very slow.

Comment: Or I can combine the approaches - that is, read part of the data using a recursive cte, then form the next recursive cte based on the data received from previous recursive cte, etc.

Comment: @ToddBarry: yes, that could be the idea.